# Is there a way to configure FileZilla to open files in read only mode?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have to access to log files in my work, and the truth I don't want to even be able to edit those files... Is there a way to open files in read only mode? or even better, to enter to a certain server in read only mode?

BTW, they give me the username and password to access to the ftp server and I don't want to create a user there to accomplish this either...

Comment: An account with read-only permissions is the only read-only mode on FTP I'm familiar with. But if you are moving batches of files for inspection, maybe consider a batch file transfer program like rsync or lftp?  You would set a script up to run a certain times, or to be executed at your convenience, that would copy files to your local machine. Then you can inspect the files locally and if you accidentally change one, you can just re-download it. lftp or rsync are probably smart enough to detect a local change and redownload the remote. You'd cut FileZilla out of the equation.

Comment: As an FTP client, the file must be downloaded to your workstation in order to be opened at all. are you concerned that if you save a change to it that filezilla will automatically PUT the new version of the file up?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, I don't want that